# How to stash an individual hunk non-interactively?

Tags: git

Let's say I have a file with several sets of changes (a.k.a. hunks), and I can generate a patch file for any individual hunk.  Much as you can stage an individual hunk with:

```
git apply --cached - < patch
```

I would like to be able to stash an individual hunk using a hunk's patch.  However I cannot get git to save a stash for an individual hunk non-interactively.  I have tried the following but they don't work in various ways:

```
git stash save --patch patch      # interactive
git stash save --patch < patch    # interactive
git stash save --patch - patch    # unknown option: -
git stash save --patch - < patch  # unknown option: -
git stash save < patch            # ignores patch and stashes all the hunks

git stash push --patch patch      # pathspec 'patch' did not match...
git stash push --patch < patch    # interactive
git stash push --patch - patch    # unknown option: -
git stash push --patch - < patch  # unknown option: -
git stash push < patch            # ignores patch and stashes all the hunks
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What would be the use case for this? Why would you not want to interactively choose which hunk to stage? (not being rude, just curious)

Comment: It's to allow stashing of hunks from [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter).

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't allow you to specify a hunk to stash by patch.  You can, however, drive the --patch option with the same letters you would use interactively.  So if you wanted to stash only the second hunk of three, you could use `printf "%s\n" n y n | git stash save -p`.

The Git testsuite does this, for example.

If you have a hunk, but not the index of that hunk in the diff, you'd have to parse the output from `git diff` in order to find the index.

Comment: That's good to know.  Is there any way to get `git stash -p` to use zero-context (-U0) hunks by default?

Comment: I don't believe so.  You can use interactive.diffFilter, but that doesn't allow you to add or remove lines.  The underlying machinery doesn't allow any -U options to be specified, and diff.context doesn't seem to have any effect.